# How to run different functions with different users inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script structured in functions which is executed using the root user. Nevertheless, it is needed to execute the most part of the script as another user. My question here is how to execute different functions using different users depending on the function that'll be executed.

Example

```
#!/bin/bash

function A() {        # Run as a non-root user
  ...
}

function B() {        # Run as a non-root user
  ...
}


function C() {        # Run as a non-root user
  ...
}

function D() {        # Run as a root user
  ...
}

function main() {
  A
  B
  C
  D
}

main
```

As said before, the script is called using the root user:

```
root@host:~# script.sh
```

The main goal here is to know if this is possible and how to do it, without changing the way the script is called (i.e. the script being called via another user but root)

Comment: You cannot run a shell function as a different user because this needs a separate process. You could run a shell script or command with `sudo -u username command`

Comment: `runuser -l user bash -c "$(declare -f somefunc); somefunc"` will run `somefunc` as `user`, but without more context we can't tell if the caveats (and there are some major ones) are relevant to you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the problem doing it the way that you did is: it apparently creates a whole new context in which it is totally separated from the main one. Besides, it'd be like put all my script inside the command substitution so that it'd be able to execute fine.

Comment: @ilwl, you have no choice but to create a new process. Bodo's initial comment an hour ago was correct in that.

Comment: @ilwl, ...if you write a loadable C module and tell bash to `dlopen()` it in you can potentially make an existing shell _drop_ permissions from root, but once you've done that you can't get root back for that process. Hence, if you want to go back from a user to root, you need to have forked off the content being done as an unprivileged user to be in a separate process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I see. Thanks for the answers! Tyvm too, Bodo. I was thinking about verifying which user is logged on and call only desirable functions to execute with that user. For instance:

`
if [ "$(whoami)" != root ]; then
  A
  B
  C
else
  D
fi
`
Of course, considering that function D is not dependent on others at all. The script would've to run twice manually.

Is it a good choice? Another option would be to create a script which could only be executed by root user, and from this script, I'd call another one by using su -l user -c "script.sh"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the help of the *runuser* command.

To use your template, this looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

function user(){
runuser -l user -c "whoami"
}

function main(){
 user
}
main
```

Comment: Aside: `function funcname() {` merges legacy ksh function syntax and POSIX sh function declaration syntax in a way that's incompatible with _both_ legacy ksh and POSIX, while having no advantages over either (and, in bash, not adding the extra behavior that the `function` keyword triggered in ksh, and so also being functionally incompatible). Just use `funcname() {` with no `function` preceding; see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete; there are relevant entries in both first and 3rd tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As a matter of fact. I guess it'd turn things more impracticable since inside 'user' function I would have others functions to be executed, and inside those functions it'd have a bunch of commands needed to be executed with this 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#work user as example
su - work -c "pwd"
```

like this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Not actually. The way you've done is actually executing a command as a different user. The question was more about executing a whole function as a certain user.